# javascript help date/display

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement

i'm trying to build up an advent calendar in which the boxes just appear when its a certain date. but i just wont work..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()

if(month == 10)
{
    document.write (month);
    document.getElementById("Ueberschrift").style.display = 'block';}
else {
    document.getElementById("Ueberschrift").style.display = 'none';}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="Ueberschrift" style="display:none">Day 1</h1>
</body></html>
```

i have no idea what to do... 
maybe you guys could help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the script below :  ( the script is running `before` it can find any `H1`)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1 id="Ueberschrift" style="display:none">Day 1</h1>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()

if(month == 10)
{
    document.write (month);
    document.getElementById("Ueberschrift").style.display = 'block';}
else {
    document.getElementById("Ueberschrift").style.display = 'none';}
</script>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/olijiv/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the script in the head section, but trigger it after the page loads:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()

    if(month == 10)
    {
        // document.write (month);
        document.getElementById("Ueberschrift").style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("Ueberschrift").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="Ueberschrift" style="display:none">Day 1</h1>
</body></html>
```

Also, the `document.write (month)` statement replaces the entire body contents, so the next statement fails because there is no longer a "Ueberschrift" element in the page. Stay away from `document.write` (use a test element and the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property).